# My Javascript click event is not getting fired with turbolinks in Rails 4

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails-4, turbolinks

My on click event is not getting fired after page:load.

once i remove the page:load and use jquery default $(document).ready() then the click event works normally but other js codes are not getting executed.

As turbolink is by default included in rails 4, so I need a way to bind the click event so that following piece of code will work.

```
$(document).on('page:load',function(){

    $(document). on("click", '#bullet-icon', function(){
         alert("not clicked");
            $('.order-today-section').ScrollTo({
                    duration: 1000
            });

    }); //end of click 

  // Other javascript codes . 

}); //end of document load.
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that turbolinks don't require a full page reload, which is the reason it is blazing fast. However, sometimes turbolinks don't go along well with other JavaScript code. One note to consider, turbolinks are optional. You don't have to use them and in certain situations it might actually be better to skip turbolinks altogether.

For instructions you can check this source: http://blog.flightswithfriends.com/post/53943440505/how-to-disable-turbolinks-in-rails-4

Comment: Yes correct. I would like to go with turbolink. it works greatly. 
But, how to bind the "click" event to work even the turbolink is active ?